# Can matter/antimatter "annihilation" produce "dark matter"?

Tags: big-bang, dark-matter, antimatter, bosons

I was thinking about the following reasoning: If a matter and antimatter reaction produces energy, this energy would have particles itself. I found out (reading...) that one (the main?) product are the photons, and that they don't have an antiparticle. Photons are Bosons, and most Bosons don't have antiparticles (or are their own, hard to figure out the difference). I also read somewhere that other Bosons may result from this reaction. This makes sense in my head, because if they had antiparticles the reaction would continue, maybe forever.

Neutralinos are hypothetical particles, superposing neutral bosons. And they are candidates to be the building blocks of the so called "dark matter".

It is assumed that in the beginning of the universe the amounts of matter and antimatter were similar, and that all of the known universe (the non dark matter at least) is just a percentage of the original matter that survived this initial reaction (during, or just after, the Big Bang).

**So, here is my question: is it possible that the dark matter is a sub-product of this initial matter-antimatter reaction?**

Would it explain the abundance of dark matter in relation to the "normal" matter ? Can it be related to the uneven dispersion of matter and dark matter in the intergalactic void or distinct galaxies? Moreover, can the dark energy have the same origin (I would not dare to point a particle for it) ? if not, where is/are my mistake(s)?

Sorry if the question is repeated or irrelevant, I'm not a physicist myself, just trying to get the big picture.

Comment: Any interaction you write down for dark matter particles, including just the interaction via gravity itself (which obviously must be present), will allow for annihilations into DM (though possibly only at a very low rate). However, since we know very little about the particle content and interactions of DM, it is basically impossible to say anything that is both quantitative and model-independent.

Comment: I thought that the annihilation was connected to presence of charge, and DM would not have charge (on WIMP model at least). Are you saying that a sort of "anti DM" would also exist? I was more interested in the origin of the DM in my question.

Comment: Whether DM is charged under electromagnetism determines whether the annihilation can occur by means of a virtual photon. Millicharged DM models exist but for it to be "dark" the charge must be fairly small. However everything is "charged" under gravity; that's the equivalence principle, and so it is basically impossible within the framework of perturbative quantum field theory to completely eliminate annihilations via virtual gravitons. The rate for this is quite small though; probably too small to ever be useful as a mechanism for producing DM...

Comment: One can posit other types of interactions (e.g. in the WIMP case DM couples to the Standard Model via the weak interaction) which will open additional production and decay channels which, depending on your model, may be useful to produce the right amount of dark matter. But we really don't know much about how DM interacts with itself or us other than gravitationally which leaves a huge variety of options on the table.

Comment: "annihilation was connected to presence of charge" Not really, eg a neutron will annihilate with an antineutron despite each of those particles having zero nett electrical charge.

Comment: Yeah, but a neutron is composed by charged particles (quarks) that may be arranged in an "antimatter" configuration. If I understood it well, to not have an "antimatter" counterpart it does not suffice to have a neutral sum of charges. Anyway, I don't see the relation to my main question.

Comment: Sorry for the delay replying, I didn't notice yiur last comment because you didn't ping me. My comment about neutrons was only in response to your comment re annihilation being associated with charge, I wasn't attempting to address your main question (BTW, the valance quarks in an antineutrons are actually antiquarks).

Comment: As for your main question, it's not possible to give it a decent answer currently because we don't know enough about DM. I guess it's plausible. However, if the theory is correct that large amounts of antimatter were present in the  very early universe then we expect that most of it got converted fairly quickly to plain old photons, and those photons were trapped until the universe cooled sufficiently to become transparent.

Comment: Thanks PM. Do we know already how the annihilation reaction may be affected by the extreme conditions of the Big Bang, such as the high temperatures? can it increase the proportion of bosons with higher mass to be produced, in relation to the photons? Can we check this idea using current models? (the reader may be free to check, it is beyond my ability)